# Download Azure Blob in Web Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, download, httpresponse

All, I am trying to find a way to download a large blob file (about 200MB) from an Asp.net MVC 4 Web Site , Here is my code snippet. Please review it .thanks.

```
string sBlobName ="xxxxx";
Response.ContentType="application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + sBlobName);

long lFileSize =200*1024*1024;
int iOffset = 0;
int iBufferSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024;//MB

while (iOffset < lFileSize)
{
    //Chunk read blob into a byte array
    var bData = StorageHelper.ChunkReadPackage(sContainerName, sPackFullPath, iOffset, iBufferSize);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bData);
    iOffset += bData.Length;
}
Response.Flush();
Response.End();

return new EmptyResult();
```

It seems After all the chunks which were read from blob were sent to client by Response.BinaryWrite(), then my Firefox could pop up the download dialog window to me .

**My Questions**

Why need Response.BinaryWrite() the whole content ? Is there anyway to make this process more efficiently? I mean if there is a way to download the stream in client side after the first chunk of blob was sent to client. Instead waiting all the content was sent to client .

Comment: Why not just use the azure storage client API?

Comment: @AbdElRaheim Sorry , I don't got your mean , Of course I am using the Azure storage API in the function `StorageHelper.ChunkReadPackage`, Then send the chunk to client . have you already review my code ? Or , Am I missing something ?

Comment: I Believe it has nothing to do with azure . So i didn't add the Azure tag in my post

Comment: It should be just a couple lines of code to upload a file.  You are making the http requests yourself.  http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/#upload-blob

Comment: @AbdElRaheim I don't have any problems with upload file to blob .this large file I had upload with azure storage api before . now My problem is how to download it more efficiently. thanks

Comment: err.  sorry I meant upload file http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/#download-blobs

Comment: doh I see, the problem is serving it to the client

Comment: @AbdElRaheim Sorry ,I have to download it from Asp.net web site. I can not make it with a winform ,wpf or silverlight app. thanks.

Comment: try setting bufferoutput to false and add the content length in the header.   Response.BufferOutput = false;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", lFileSize);

Comment: @AbdElRaheim `Response.BufferOutput = false` is enough. What is the purpose of the `Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", lFileSize)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Response.BufferOutput = false;`  It works.